# Hided launcher does not show urgent icons

Tags: unity, launcher, 15.04, bug-reporting

I'd like to use auto-hide option for the launcher. And in the other side, I use Pidgin messenger application, in this application when a buddy becomes on-line or off-line, its icon in the launcher starts to shaking. When the launcher is visible, there is no problem. But when it is not visible, its icon should slide inside while it is shaking and then go off the screen. Such behavior works fine in 14.10 and older versions.

But in 15.04, launcher does not show urgent icons when it is not visible. Is it possible to getting this functionality back? Or is it a bug?